# AttributeError: 'new_class' property is not defined

Tags: python, owl

Yesterday, I has a lecture when I was supposed to present my work. I have tested my App several times and it used to work. However yesterday, my App failed to work in front of my boss. He got upset and he think I have done nothing. It's so humiliating...

I have this bug.

```
AttributeError: 'new_class' property is not defined.
```

I don't understand why because it used to work before... This is so weird.

```
python_created = get_ontology('localhost:8000/home/new_python_created.owl')
with python_created:
    '''
    global() makes us able to create variables dynamically.
    For example:
    gloval('Var%s' % 'toto') = 'toto' create a variable Vartoto (Var + toto) equals to toto.
    types.new_class makes us able to create classes dynamically
    For example:
    newClass = types.new_class('className', (SuperClass,))

    In order to create an ontology, we need to create dynamicals variables and classes
    '''
    for node in LevelOrderIter(hps):
        if node.parent is not None:
            # print("{} is a {}".format(node.name, node.parent.name))

            if node.parent.name == 'Thing':
                globals()['%s' % node.name] = types.new_class(node.name, (Thing, ))
                pass
            else:
                globals()['%s' % node.name] = types.new_class(node.name, (python_created['{}'.format(node.parent.name)], ))
        else:
            print("{}".format(node.name))
    AllDisjoint([python_created['{}'.format(node.name)] for node in LevelOrderIter(hps, maxlevel=2, filter_=lambda n: n.name != 'Thing')])
    '''
    print([node.name for node in LevelOrderIter(hps, filter_=lambda n:
        n.parent is not None and n.parent.name == 'genres'
    )])
    '''

python_created.save(file=join(dirname(__file__), "new_python_created.owl"))
```

```
2021-08-31 09:39:23.229172: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-08-31 09:39:23.229230: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 31, 2021 - 09:39:35
Django version 3.2.4, using settings 'OntologyLearningPlatform.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Thing
Internal Server Error: /create_ontology/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/adam/Documents/OntologyLearningPlatform/OLApp/views.py", line 201, in create_ontology
    hps.create_ontology(txtfile, '{}'.format(ontofile))
  File "/home/adam/Documents/OntologyLearningPlatform/OLApp/create_ontology/hypernym_hearst_pattern.py", line 222, in create_ontology
    globals()['%s' % node.name] = types.new_class(node.name, (Thing, ))
  File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owlready2/entity.py", line 550, in __getattr__
    if not Prop: raise AttributeError("'%s' property is not defined." % attr)
AttributeError: 'new_class' property is not defined.
[31/Aug/2021 09:48:45] "POST /create_ontology/ HTTP/1.1" 500 79659
```

PS:

I have change types.new_class with type but I don't understand why it failed.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the complete traceback.

Comment: I don't have enough space to provide the traceback

Comment: Internal Server Error: /create_ontology/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

Comment: File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/adam/Documents/OntologyLearningPlatform/OLApp/views.py", line 201, in create_ontology
    hps.create_ontology(txtfile, '{}'.format(ontofile))
  File "/home/adam/Documents/OntologyLearningPlatform/OLApp/create_ontology/hypernym_hearst_pattern.py", line 222, in create_ontology
    globals()['%s' % node.name] = types.new_class(node.name, (Thing, ))

Comment: File "/home/adam/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owlready2/entity.py", line 550, in __getattr__
    if not Prop: raise AttributeError("'%s' property is not defined." % attr)
AttributeError: 'new_class' property is not defined.
[31/Aug/2021 09:56:08] "POST /create_ontology/ HTTP/1.1" 500 79738

Comment: Put it in your question.

Comment: So I have put it now. I have change "types.new_class(node.name, (Thing, ))" with "type(node.name, (Thing, ), {})"

Comment: I don't understand why it works for type but not for types.new_class

Comment: I cannot produce this error, I can parse and create a subclass axiom via `types.new_class` - check your Python libs